# Draw a human 3d body, Silverlight or Adobe Flash

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, flash

Which technology to choose, that gives me the possibility to draw a 3d human in browser, with tricks like move the body with mouse, with less cpu use. 
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what is a target market of your program.

Silverlight: is C#, 3D modelling is possible, there is even port of Silverlight of Mono [MoonLight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight), but basically yuo should consider that your clients in this case will be Windows OS owners, and considering a OSes destribution information from [Os destribution worldwide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_comparison), you're on winner train.

So looking on your tags: C#, I would say go for Silverlight.

There is another really good product for 3D in browsing, like [WebGL](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki_1_15/index.php/WebGL_and_OpenGL), but it's currently not supported of IE, for security concerns, which doesn't mean that will not be supported in future, but.. you know, for now it's not. Here is explanation: [Microsoft not going to support WebGL](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2011/06/microsoft-no-way-to-support-webgl-and-meet-our-security-needs.ars). If you are ready to say "no" to IE (at least for now), it's a good choice.

So for now, I personally, would suggest to use Silverlight 3D. Just google "Silbverlight 3D samples" and you will be given plenty of samples available on inetrnet.

**EDIT**

Good comparing article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188499/Web-goes-3D-does-advertising-too-The-WebGL-Silverl.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: Regarding WebGL, it will probably be the preferred format for 3D on the web one day, but right now I would regard it as experimental, and not as fully supported by non-IE browsers. For example in Safari it has to be actively enabled by the user, using the Develop menu, so most Safari/Mac users will probably not se WebGL content. According to http://caniuse.com/#search=WebGL about 30% of users now have "partial" support for WebGL.

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight 4 is not as competent in 3d rendering as Flash is.
Having said that, Silverlight 5 will have greater support for 3d thanks to its XNA integration

**EDIT:** It seems I was rather fast to judge - the official 3d support fo flash (aka molehill) is still under incubation, but flash still has some impressive community-based libraries for 3d still making it (IMO) the more mature solution (Add to that it's larger cross-platform and user support).

Answer (score 1):

Flash doesn't really have 3D graphics support, although there are a couple of libraries available. Silverlight *also* doesn't do 3D. So, really, the answer is "none of the above work all that well."

If you're willing to force your clients to use a current browser, you can use HTML5 and WebGL to render 3D objects without too much trouble.

Comment: Flash finally does have proper 3D graphics support (but is beta at the moment) [http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplatform/2011/03/flash-platform-molehill-and-gaming-updates.html](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplatform/2011/03/flash-platform-molehill-and-gaming-updates.html)